# Proper way to include external librarie into Angular-CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to use [Angular2-localstorage](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage) in my Angular-CLI app.

I followed the guide here:
[Guide to include external libs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs)

But I keep getting this error:

> zone.js:101 GET
>   http://localhost:4200/node_modules/angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter.js
>   404 (Not Found)

This is my system-config.ts file (important parts):

```
const map: any = {
  'angular2-localstorage': 'node_modules/angular2-localstorage'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'angular2-localstorage': {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
};
```

And angular-cli-build.js:

```
var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter.ts'
    ]
  });
};
```

Comment: Add the format for `angular2-localstorage` in packages and you should map js files only in `vendorNpmFiles` (you have ts there)

Comment: I ended up using another plugin. This didn't work good.